# How do I see atom editor's entire prompt?

Tags: atom-editor

How do I see the entire prompt at the bottom? Right now it cuts off at (use esnext option) o...

[image]

Comment: To begin with, it would be useful to know which of the many JSHint packages is producing the error.

Comment: @jlei: how did you get on have you managed to sort our your JSHint package?

Comment: @RichardSlater i haven't tried linter-jshint before but wanted to just stick with jshint because it's suppose to work better with react.

Comment: @idleberg I only have the jshint package

Comment: @jlei: to be **totally** clear are you talking about this [jshint](https://atom.io/packages/jshint) package?

Comment: @RichardSlater yes that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are tied into using the [jshint](https://atom.io/packages/jshint) package then you won't be able to view the full message in the status bar, however you can access the full message by hovering over the gutter for the line that is causing the error:

[image: View full Error in JSHint]

Be warned that this package is now depricated:

> I failed to [find an active maintainer](https://github.com/sindresorhus/atom-jshint/issues/141). See [linter-jshint](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-jshint) for an alternative. However, I would strongly recommend trying out [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) ([Atom plugin](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint)) instead. It's just so much better than JSHint. [XO](https://github.com/sindresorhus/xo) ([Atom plugin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/atom-linter-xo)), which is an ESLint wrapper with sensible defaults, is also a good choice.

Comment: Thanks! this was so helpful and i'll keep in mind that it's deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at the [linter](https://atom.io/packages/linter) package and the [jshint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-jshint) package for linter.  Using linter will give you a rich user interface and a way of interacting with the error messages:

[image: Screenshot of linter-jshint]